# Completely remove sendmail

Tags: uninstall, sendmail

How do I completely remove sendmail? I have tried the following:

```
apt-get remove sendmail
apt-get purge sendmail
```

Sendmail is still there and running, how do I completely remove it and all config files?

Comment: hello @jphreak even i plan to remove sendmail as it working slow.. have any alternate suggestion

Answer (score 49):

To remove send mail completely you have to use:

```
apt-get purge sendmail*
```

(Note the `*` at the end.)

Thanks to this post here on Ubuntu forum:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916606